# Recover Postgres Streaming Replication Slave from Archived Wal Logs

Tags: postgresql

I have set up a Postgres Hot Standby server by Streaming Replication. But My Standby server is asking for an old wal archive log which is currently not in Master's pg_xlog directory. But the file exists in the wal archive backup directory.

How can I configure Standby to read this file from backup directory? Or any way to manually copy this file to Standby Server ?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to add a `restore_command` to `recovery.conf` that can restore files from the WAL archive.

Then restart the standby, and it should be able to recover.

When the standby cannot get the required WAL via streaming replication, it tries `restore_command`. When that fails, it tries streaming replication again, and so on in an endless loop.